# Can I safely assume that if(true) and if(false) will be optimized?

Tags: c++, optimization, g++, clang++

In my code at some point I have a function with a `bool value` template parameter. The implementation of the function in the `true` and `false`cases are pretty much identical, except for one line. So I thought I would just put an `if(value)` statement to avoid rewriting the same function twice. When the function is called, `value` is determined at compile time so the `if` statement reduces to an `if(true)` or an `if(false)`.
Now, I wonder: is it safe to assume that any reasonable compiler (say `g++`, `clang++`, ...) will optimize that statement?

Yes, performance is critical, yes, the function is immensely lightweight so that even a single `if` would affect speed, yes this function needs to be executed a gazillion of times on a real-time device on which many human lives depend.

Comment: If the bool is a template parameter, why not specialize for true and false and get a guaranteed compile time evaluation? Or am I misunderstanding? Some sample code would be nice.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely a solution. As I wrote, the two specializations would be identical up to one line, so I preferred to avoid repeating a long bunch of code twice.

Comment: It would require more code and/or duplicated code no ? [EDIT : was responding to DeiDei]

Comment: For GCC and Clang, yes even in debug builds: [gcc -O0 still optimizes out "unused" code. Is there a compile flag to change that?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39832958) .  For MSVC, only in optimized builds.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short answer is "yes".  The compiler will evaluate constant expressions, and in branches, it will figure out if the branch is always or never taken.

Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void test(void) {
  if (false) {
    puts("Hello, world!");
  }
}
```

Here's the output assembly:

```
test():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Note that no call to `puts` is even emitted.  This is GCC 6.3 with no optimizations enabled (optimization is turned *off* and this still happens the right way).

See: https://godbolt.org/g/PJ7lSf

Comment: Great! Just what I was hoping for.

Comment: @MatteoMonti If this answers your question, then you should accept it.

Comment: Sure sure! You can't accept an answer too early, I was just waiting a few minutes :)

Comment: Note that some compilers (like MSVC) will only do this optimization if optimization is enabled.  A debug build in MSVC will actually use some asm instructions to put a `0` in a register and test it, and the dead code will be there in the binary.  Unless you use C++17 `if constexpr`.  (https://godbolt.org/z/Mj5aEoYqs). But performance of debug builds is usually unimportant, and optimized builds will optimize this to just a `ret`, like GCC and Clang, or any optimizing compiler.  This is a very easy and important optimization so it just comes down to debug-build semantics.