# Is there any problem in jumping into if(false) block?

Tags: c++, duffs-device

I've read already a couple times (e.g. here [Compiler: What if condition is always true / false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034558/compiler-what-if-condition-is-always-true-false)) that any decent c++ compiler will opt-out something like

```
if(false)
{
 ...
}
```

But what if there is an intentional jump into this `if(false)` block. I'm having something like this in mind

```
#include <iostream>

void func(int part){
    switch (part) {
    case 0:{
        if(false)
            case 1:{std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;}
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    func(0);
    func(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Is any decent c++ compiler going to respect the jump or will there eventually going to be some problems with opting-out?

Comment: Does that even compile?

Comment: Compiles ok https://godbolt.org/z/8VZw1w  and I think it ok from a standards perspective

Comment: gcc 7.4.0 no problem :)

Comment: The compilers job is to generate the code with proper side effects. Why would a c++ compiler not going to "respect" (what does that mean?) the "jump"? What "problems with opting-out" do you see? Do you ask if the function can be optimized to `if (part == 1) std::cout << .... ;` ?

Comment: Yeah, this is something that you probably shouldn't do at all.  Find a better way to do whatever it is that you're trying to do.

Comment: Keep in mind that compilers are allowed to optimize anything as long as the effect is still the same. So if this isn't breaking any rules (UB, ill-formed, syntax errors, etc), then the compiler has to honor it . But again, that's only if you're not breaking rules.

Comment: @KamilCuk First I was concerned - like others here - if that is even going to compile for all compilers. Then I was thinking how much of OPT flags could play a role, something like could -O3 cause problems here...

Comment: @Chipster So am I breaking any rules here?

Comment: if you have such code in your code base, compiler bugs are the least of your problems

Comment: This should be illegal, IMHO.

Comment: @Jeffrey fair enough. I'm deferring functions and this is what it ended up to be. I also dont know how much different it could look...

Comment: @ezegoing No you are not breaking any rules. This will print `hello` once through the `func(1)` call and that can't be changed by the compiler.

Comment: `case 0:{
            case 1:
   }` definitely feels like is should be breaking rules because you are jumping into the middle of a block. Although the ancient now out of favor `goto` could do things like this I think, so maybe not.

Comment: @Chipster `switch` is a `goto` table. It uses labels exactly like a `goto` does. And it has the same rules about skipping declarations as `goto`. It's no surprise it behaves exactly like a `goto`. Edit : This is why it's able to produce the example used in this question.

Comment: @jxh, my question is really bout the if(false) jump and not the jump itself, should have chosen a silly goto then. I don't care about the duffs toy, this stuff is being used by my colleagues frequently. So i dont see a duplicate to this linked thread :S

Comment: @ezegoing [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58631602/edit) and add that information in.

Comment: @ezegoing: The compiler can perform dead code elimination if the code is dead. The code after `case 1:` isn't dead. The reason it isn't dead is because your code is Duff's Device. QED.

Comment: @Chipster well that is the question title *Is there any problem in jumping into if(false) block? [duplicate]
* lol and the whole question...

Comment: @ezegoing Yes, but since it's now been confused as a duplicate, it's a good idea to add a statement why it's not a duplicate in the question.

Comment: If your question is really about "jumping", you can rewrite your example with a `goto` instead. But, the crux of the answer is the same: if the code is reachable via a jump, then it is not dead code, and so the compiler will not apply DCE.

Comment: I do want to stress: The question was well composed and straightforward to understand. I am just saying if you recognized the `switch` into `if` construction as Duff's Device, you would have known the code would not be subject to being optimized out. Upvote for the question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code doesn't appear to be Undefined Behavior. Therefore any optimizations are not allowed to produce any effects which would affect the behavior of the code.

Note: Related to this *kind* of code, one thing you are not allowed to do is "goto" over definitions of local variables. But this code doesn't do that, so no problem.

Another note: If you have this kind of code in a "real" (not toy, experiment, obfuscation exercise etc) program, you should really refactor it into something which doesn't elicit quite so many WTFs from anybody reading the code.

Comment: The technique is a well-known one, so it should be idiomatic in the code bases that use it. If it isn't used in a code base, then it may be best not to introduce it.

Comment: @jxh Interesting. In fact now that I think of it, I could have had a use case for exactly this a week or two ago... except it wouldn't ever fly in code review :-D

Comment: @hyde dont forget to cite me XD