# Declare class member variables inside class member functions

Tags: c++

Is there any technique or compiler extension keyword to declare class member variables inside class member functions? Something like

```cpp
struct test_t{
    void operator ()(){
        instance_local int i = 0;
    }
};
```

The best that came in my mind was using `thread_local` and then executing the member function inside another thread, but this would be too ugly to be useful.

---

EDIT: example

Well I'm really sorry for the following probably confusing example (it is related to my question yesterday [Is there any problem in jumping into if(false) block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631602/is-there-any-problem-in-jumping-into-iffalse-block?noredirect=1#comment103571413_58631602)). I really tried to make a less confusing up...

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#define instance_local thread_local

struct A{
    A(int i) :
        i(i)
    {

    }
    void dosomethinguseful(){
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    int i;
};
struct task1{
    int part;
    task1() : part(0){}
    void operator ()(){
        int result_of_calculation;
        switch (part) {
        case 0:{
            //DO SOME CALCULATION
            result_of_calculation = 5;
            instance_local A a(result_of_calculation);
            if(false) 
              case 1:{ a.dosomethinguseful();}
            part++;
        }
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};
int main(){
    task1 t;
    t();
    t();
    return 0;
}
```

`instance_local A a(result_of_calculation);` that is what i could get from such a keyword instead of making a smart pointer for `a`.

Comment: Why not just create a regular member variable?

Comment: Consider non-blocking function wrapper, where certain blocks are executed on each function call. So that function shall be called repeatedly until it finishes or succeeds. If you do like this you might have a class instance only being constructable after e.g. block 2. So the workaround now is making smart pointer member variables, but that boilerplate code adds up. Ill include an example if needed.

Comment: Yeah I think you'd need to give an example.

Comment: @ezegoing An example would most definitely help.

Comment: I hope not!! Can you imagine trying to maintain code when reading the class definition can't be be relied on for determining the definition of the class because part of it could be buried in some function implementation?

Comment: You cannot add or remove member variables of a class at run time.

Comment: Sry for taking me so long with the example and sry for this silly example. But that is the case I was thinking of that such a keyword may come useful.

Comment: @ezegoing you're describing a coroutine! They are in C++20.  Currently, it's implemented as a dynamically allocated object which his layout can be determined by the compiler backend for optimisation. The way to emulate that in C++17 or older is to implemente a state machine (your switch) + a state. The state would be better off as a member

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Oh man I feel so bad now. All these days and hours wasting into this and you tell me now there is coroutines in c++20... Guess I'm better off switching to coroutines then instead of reinventing the wheel. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also time travelling ;)

Comment: And, great example of why context matters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing a coroutine. Here a rough draft of what it could look like (I'm not an expert in coroutine)

```
auto task1() -> some_awaitable_type {
    result_of_calculation = 5;
    A a(result_of_calculation);

    co_yield;

    a.dosomethinguseful();
}
```

This could be called like this:

```
some_awaitable_type maybe_do_something = task1();
// calculation done here

// dosomethinguseful called here
co_await maybe_do_something();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not. The compiler needs to know the structure of the class without compiling all the method implementations. If you could slip `instance_local int foo` into a method body, that would make the size of the data structure 4 bytes larger.

On a more principled level, it's not good to hide data. The equivalent feature for global variables that you might be thinking of, static local variables, is a carryover from C that is widely considered to be an anti-pattern:
[Why are static variables considered evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil)

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, no.

You could define a:

```
static std::map<test_t*, int> is;
```

…where the first part of each element is a `this` pointer.

**But, why?**

Make a member variable.

Comment: The map idea would fail if an instance is allocated at the same address as a previously deleted instance. It would also leak memory.

Comment: @interjay It's certainly not a good idea! You're probably right in that I could have emphasised that more, with reasons.